# Delphi - TDBGrid won't update

Tags: delphi

I am working on a Delphi project. I am using FireDAC driver (MSSQL database).

I have a problem with TDBGrid. It won't update. For example, when I enter more than one query into FireDAC SQL editor, the following error appears: "310 - cannot execute command returning result sets. hint: use Open method for SELECT-like commands.":

```
select table1.column1
from (table1
inner join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1);

select * from table2;
```

How and where (could you show sample code) should I enter my queries to work?

Answer (score 1):

> The following error appears: "310 - cannot execute command returning result sets. hint: use Open method for SELECT-like commands.":

Take the hint FireDAC is giving you: In order to be able to populate a DBGrid, you must call .Open on the dataset (FDQuery?) you are using, and you can only do that if the SQL returns only one result set. In other words, it must contain only one SELECT statement. If you need multiple SELECTs concurrently, use multiple FDQueries. It's that simple ...

E.g.  Put this code in your form or datamodule

```
FDQuery1.Sql.Text := 'select table1.column1'
                   + ' from (table1'
                   + ' inner join table2 on table1.column1=table2.column1)';

FDQuery1.Open;

FDQuery2.Sql.Text := 'select * from table2';

FDQuery2.Open;
```

Btw, the title of your q is not quite right.  It's not that the DBGrid will not update, but that it can only display data from the dataset feeding it (via a TDataSource) while the dataset is open.  Once you can get your FDQuery(?) to open successfully, the DBGrd will display whatever data has been SELECTed by it.  Make sure you call `.Close` on your dataset when you have finished using it.

Comment: For some reason, FDQuery2 won't work with DataSource2. Could you explain why?

Comment: Sorry, of course I can't!  How can I guess what you mean by "won't work"? Add the code you are using in your project to your q.